# R Separate name string based on all caps versus normal case

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of full name, where the last name is all caps, the first name is normal case. I would like to separate this into last name and first name using the separate function. I'm not great at regex, though tried a few things, none quite right. Here is a sample:

```
my_column_of_names <- c("DI VICENZO John", "SMITH Anne Marie", "O'ROURKE Paddy", "MARTIN-JONES Jim Rae")
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: In which language/environment are you using regex?

Comment: R, I added it as a tag (and in the title), though forgot to mention in the text. I have updated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using `tidyr`'s function `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(my_column_of_names) %>%
  extract(my_column_of_names,
          into = c("Family", "First"),
          regex = "([A-Z\\s'-]+(?![a-z]))[,\\s]+(.*)")
        Family      First
1   DI VICENZO       John
2        SMITH Anne Marie
3     O'ROURKE      Paddy
4 MARTIN-JONES    Jim Rae
```

How the `regex` works:

Essentially we divide the strings into two capturing groups, one for `Familiy` names, one for `First` names; what's in between them is 'mentioned' in `regex` but not captured and therefore not extracted:

- `([A-Z\\s'-]+(?![a-z]))`: the 1st capture group, matching any upper-case letters, whitespaces, hyphens, and apostrophes occurring one or more times **unless** the immediately next character is lower-case (this restriction is expressed in the negative lookahead `(?![a-z])`)
- `[,\\s]+`: a comma or/and whitespace occurring one or more times
- `(.*)`: the 2nd capture group, which matches anything after the prior

**EDIT**:

Here's how `tidyr`'s function `separate` would do the job:

```
data.frame(my_column_of_names) %>%
  separate(my_column_of_names,
          into = c("Family", "First"),
          sep = "(?<=[A-Z][A-Z])\\s+(?=[A-Z][a-z])|,\\s")
```

Unlike `extract`, which works by describing the string in full and separating the bits of interest with capture groups, `separate` works by defining a splitting point. In the present case, that takes a bit of regex syntax:

Here we define two alternative splitting points:

- `(?<=[A-Z][A-Z])\\s+(?=[A-Z][a-z])`: first splitting point - a whitespace occurring one or more times that is (i) preceded by two upper-case letters and (ii) followed by one upper-case and one lower-case letter
- `|`: alternation marker
- `,\\s`: second splitting point - a simple comma followed by whitespace

Comment: Thank you so much. This was perfect. I had tried several things, though was looking for a quick solution, so didn't elaborate, so am grateful for your patience and quick reply. One question - perhaps off topic, do you know why this would work using extract() when it does not for separate()?

Comment: see my edited solution for an answer